# Missing "schedule delay" connector in Azure Logic Apps (Standard)

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I want to implement a delay in my Azure Logic Apps (standard) but unable to find it. The screenshots below shows it it available in the consumption but missing from standard. I have checked it in both 'Built-in' as well as 'Azure'.

**Consumption:**

[image]

**Standard:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I understood that Schedule Delay can be found in Stateful Workflow but not Stateless of standard logic app.

**STATEFUL WORKFLOW**

[image]

**STATELESS WORKFLOW**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is this a limitation? Will it be added to the stateless workflow in the future? Also, it would be great to update a documentation since I did not see this listed anywhere.

Comment: I can confirm I am able to use it with stateful. I think this has to be by design because stateless workflows are supposed to be used for less time consuming tasks and delay can cause some problems there.